# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS won't connect to external monitor after suspending

Tags: external-monitor

I have an HP Zbook with windows dual boot and Ubuntu 20.04LTS. I don't know if my computer has always done this but I just noticed that I can't connect external monitors after my computer suspends. When I start the computer and connect external monitors everything works fine. However, once it is suspended it will no longer see any external monitors.

Anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Solved.

I tried upgrading the nvidea-driver using with a tested driver and it didn't fix it.

However, it started working after I `sudo apt uptade` and `sudo apt upgrade`